# Error while launching the app on emulator shows unfortunately location has stopped

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I got the following error:

```
11-12 03:49:31.085 2207-2217/com.google.android.gms E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                  java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                                                      at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:190)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
                                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1142)
                                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1131)
                                                                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:261)
                                                                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:261)
                                                                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:261)
                                                                      at ivm.g(:com.google.android.gms:204)
                                                                      at ivm.e(:com.google.android.gms:176)
                                                                      at ivh.h(:com.google.android.gms:27519)
                                                                      at ong.b(:com.google.android.gms:277)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.googlehelp.service.ClearHelpHistoryChimeraIntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms:36)
                                                                      at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms:95)
                                                                      at bie.run(:com.google.android.gms:1873)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here's my code:

```
package com.newboston.location;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.CharArrayBuffer;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DETAILS.db";
  private static final String TABLE_DETAILS = "details";
  private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "_name";
  private static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "_phone_no";

  public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String query = "CREATE TABELE " + TABLE_DETAILS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DETAILS);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
  }

  public void addDetails(Details details) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, details.get_name());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_DETAILS, null, values);
    db.close();
  }

  public void deleteDetails(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_DETAILS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + " =\"" + name + "\";");
    db.close();


  }

  public String printDetails() {
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DETAILS + " WHERE 1";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!(c.isAfterLast()))
    {
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"))!=null)
        {
            dbString+=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            dbString+="\n";
        }
         c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    c.close();
    return dbString;
  }
}
```

I'm not able to find where I haven't closed any resource though I have closed all the database I have opened.But log cat shows still error for same.

Comment: Is this stacktrace from you app? If it is, your app should be somewhere in the stack trace.

Comment: so how do i resolve it? @PeriHartman

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your comment. My primary question is: does your app work or does it crash?

Comment: Your package name does not appear to be in this logcat. Are you sure these are errors from your app?

Comment: it crashes every time open it in my device.It shows Unfortunately,Location(My app name) has stopped.@PeriHartman

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed the previous version of the app on the emulator before the update, i will suggest you first clear your app from your emulator or uninstalling the app completely from the emulator before you can go on.

Answer (score 0):

I would have added this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Have you added proper permissions in your manifest.
uninstall the app from emulator if already present and try rerunning the app.

Check this query what is 1?

`String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DETAILS + " WHERE 1";`